# Entity Framework 4: What causes .Take(10) to return 20 records?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I believe I am doing the following:

```
 var myQuery = Products.Where( p => p.deptid = 3);
 var myCount = Products.Count();
 var myResult = myQuery.OrderBy( p => p.deptname).Skip(10).Take(10);
 //then return an object with a count property and a List<Product> property.
```

Sometimes, this returns double the take amount.

There are a few layers to my solution, namely a Repository and a Service layer.  I am pretty sure that I am not ordering, skipping, nor taking in my repository, and this is the service layer code.  What could cause myResult to have more than 10 records when I take 10 records?

Comment: Maybe show how you "return an object with a count property and a List<Product> property"

Comment: What do you mean by `Sometimes`? in this cases how many item are in your Products list, and in other case how many are there? I bet you should have some other codes which causes to this problem. for seeing this add `.ToList()`to the end of Take(10)

Comment: Yep, something else is causing the problem. First of all, you have `.Take(10)` but no `.ToList()` at the end. So `myResult` is an `IQueryable<T>`. Show the code where you materialize a query into a concrete collection.

Comment: I am with RPM1984, try adding .ToList() or .ToArray() to execute the query. Leaving it as IQuerable<Product> leaves room for the query to change before it is executed with delayed execution.

Comment: Profile your SQL. That should give you a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am fairly sure that I did an OrderBy() then did another OrderBy().Skip().Take().  The Skip().Take() probably used the inner ID to select records.

I went through all application layers to ensure that only one OrderBy().Skip().Take() occurred, and all was fixed.

However, I cannot recreate the problem to save my life.  I don't know if this was the solution.

Comment: Chalk it up to one of those mystery gremlins in EF.